# Javascript check all checkboxes in a table / asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a table with rows in, and each row has a few `<td>` elements. The last element has a checkbox in.
They are in a `<div>` which is set to `runat="server"`. I have another checkbox on the page called "chkAll" that when clicked, I want to javascript check or uncheck all of the checkboxes in my table.

I'm not very good at Javascript, so I am not sure what to do. I added a javascript onclick method, and put document.getelementbyid and put in the div.clientID, but I wasnt sure what to do from there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

once you have the the `<div>` element as a reference, use `getElementsByTagName()` to get the `<input>` elements, then check the `type` property, if it's a checkbox then set it's `checked` property the same as the `checked` property of the checkbox `chkAll`. For example

```
function toggleCheckBoxes(elem) {

    var div = document.getElementById('<% = divid.ClientID %>');

    var chk = div.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var len = chk.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (chk[i].type === 'checkbox') {
            chk[i].checked = elem.checked;
        }
    }        
}
```

and then attach this function as a click event handler of the `chkAll` element

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" onclick="toggleCheckBoxes(this)" />
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/irufo)**. add **/edit** to the URL to see the code

Comment: no problem - you might also want to set up a click event handler on each checkbox in the `<div>` to check the `checked` property of the other checkboxes - if all of them are not checked, then uncheck `chkAll` checkbox. if all of them are checked, check the `chkAll` checkbox. I'll leave this as en exercise for you, now that you know how to get checkboxes and check their `checked` property

Answer (score 3):

Since you are new to javascript I won't recommend using jQuery. Get basic ideas of javascript and then use jQuery.

Try this one

```
function CheckAll()
{
    var tab = document.getElementById ( "tbl1" ); // table with id tbl1
    var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName ( "input" );
    var len = elems.length;

    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        if ( elems[i].type == "checkbox" )
        {
            elems[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are confident of using jQuery then you can use

```
$("#tbl1 input[type='checkbox']").attr ( 'checked' , true );
```

in the onclick function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am trying to get it working, but it cannot find the table, I guess because I create the table in the codebehind dynamically.

Comment: use the ClientID of the table in the JavaScript function. If the function is in the aspx markup, you can use the server-side tags `<%= tableid.ClientID %>` to render out the generated client id for the table in the HTML markup sent to the client

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery - it makes javascript much easier and less verbose.

I think a solution to your problem can be found here:

http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/7/9/Check-All-Checkboxes-with-JQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

**in aspx:**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" onclick="javascript:CheckUncheckall(this);" Text="Select" runat="server" />
            <table id="tbl" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="A" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="B" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Text="C" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" Text="D" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" Text="E" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**and the javascript below:**

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CheckUncheckall(chk) {
    var chks = document.getElementById("<% = tbl.ClientID %>").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i<chks.length; i++) {
        if(chks[i].type == "checkbox") chks[i].checked= chk.checked;
    }
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to javascript check or uncheck
>   all of the checkboxes in my table

```
<table id="goofy">...</table>

<a href="#" onclick="f(); return false;">Click me to check all boxes in table</a>
```

And JavaScript:

```
function f() {
    var inputs_in_table = document.getElementById("goofy").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i<inputs_in_table.length; i++) {
        if(inputs_in_table[i].type == "checkbox") inputs_in_table[i].checked= true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have created a modified version using this script where you can pass table name and checkbox name dynamically.
[Click here to get more infomarion](http://amitpathak.net/web/check-all-asp-net-checkbox-without-postback-in-a-table)

```
function checkedAll(container,chkID)
{

var tab = document.getElementById ( container ); // get table  id  which contain check box
var elems = tab.getElementsByTagName ( “input” );

for ( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ )
{

if ( elems[i].type == “checkbox” )
{

if ( document.getElementById(chkID).checked ==true)

elems[i].checked = true;

else

elems[i].checked = false;
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save on looping elements here by using jquery to directly access checkboxes directly and then looping them.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){ 
    this.checked = true  
});
```

If you wanted to isolate a particular part of the page:

```
$(mydiv).find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){ 
    this.checked = true 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkall').click(
 function () {
   $('#divid').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
     this.checked = $('#checkall').is(':checked')
    });
});
```

In this, all checkboxes checked and unchecked by a single checkbox (`checkall` - id)