# How would I create a javaScript function that counts how many checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a program that adds 500 to the sum for each checkbox that is checked so I would like to know what the JS is for finding how many checkboxes are checked in a form. Thanks!

Note: I can't use jQuery, it has to be straight JS, sorry folks!

Comment: jquery allowed?  because it would be a quicker function.  Also do they have all the same name? or can they? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563240/how-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes

Answer (score 4):

Use the `:checked` selector supported by [`element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzU6u/)

```
var checkedCheckboxes = yourForm.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
```

Therefore to get the sum you can do:

```
var sum = checkedCheckboxes.length * 500;
```

Comment: Supported since FF3.5, Chrome 1, Opera 10, Safari 3.2 and IE9!

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
var $checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");

alert($checked.length);
```

Comment: @abc123 You do not need jQuery, the native `querySelectorAll` function supports the `:checked` selector.

Comment: @plalx and that's why your answer is better, i didn't say this requires jQuery to solve, I was saying this answer by Steve does.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Without jquery, compatible with older browsers like IE6-8.

```
var form = document.getElementById('id-of-form');
var list = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
var count = 0;
for (var idx=0, len = list.length; idx < len; ++idx) {
  if (list[idx].checked) ++count;
}
alert(count);
```