# Display all selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm trying to display all selected checkboxes from this form.

```
<form name="myform">
        Select a check box: <br> <br>
        Check Box 0: <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox" checked> <br>
        Check Box 1: <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox"> <br>
        Check Box 2: <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox"> <br>
        Check Box 3: <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox"> <br> <br>
        <input type="button" name="button" Value="Click Me" onClick="getCheckedBoxes(this.form)">
</form>
```

Here is JS code. I'm stuck here now and can't make it working. Thank you in advance.

```
function getCheckedBoxes(checkBox) {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(checkBox);
      var checkboxesChecked = [];

      for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
         if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i]);
         }
      }
      return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
    }

    var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("checkBox");

    alert ("Check box " + checkedBoxes + " is selected ");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all checked checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563240/how-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes)

Comment: You are correct I took the code form someone's answer on this question and tried to adopt it, but it was unsuccessfully. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @mplungjan I have updated the code. Now when you open the page it displays that "Check box null is selected". What do I need to do next?

Comment: Do you want the number of the checked checkboxes or their indexes? You did not have any value on the boxes so there is nothing else to display - also I missed you PASS the name of the box, so you can now remove the quotes inside the function

Comment: @mplungjan Let's take an example: I have checked first one and third one box as checked and I want an alert box to show indexes of the boxes which were checked.

Comment: See my answer. You need to alert inside the function you call onclick

Comment: Do you want just the numbers of checkboxes selected or do you want their references?

Comment: @Qwerty Thanks for help, but mplungjan already helped me.

Comment: @EdvinAntonov That's right, but I am asking what are you doing with those checkboxes then? Are you interacting with them later?

Comment: @Qwerty I needed only to display checked boxes indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alert inside the function you call onclick and you need to store the index instead of the object. If you store the object you will alert

```
Check box: [object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement] is selected
```

instead of the index.

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9y36p/)

```js
function getCheckedBoxes(boxName) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(boxName); 
  var checkboxesChecked = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      checkboxesChecked.push(i); // or i+1 if you want 1-based 
    }
  }
  return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : "none";
}

function count(name) {
  alert("Checked boxes: " + getCheckedBoxes(name));
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  Select a check box: <br> <br> Check Box 0: <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox" checked> <br> Check Box 1: <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox"> <br> Check Box 2: <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox"> <br> Check Box 3: <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox">  <br> <br>
  <input type="button" name="button" Value="Click Me" onClick="count('checkBox')">
</form>
```

Update using

- selector
- event listener
- spread operator

I needed to update the HTML to have IDs on the checkbox OR read the label content

```js
function getCheckedBoxes(boxName) {
  var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("[name="+boxName+"]:checked");
  var ids = [...checkedBoxes].map(x => x.id)
  return ids.length===0?"":ids.join(", ");
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function() {
  console.log(
    getCheckedBoxes(this.getAttribute("data-name"))
  )  
});
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  Select a check box:<br/> 
  <label>Check Box 0: <input id="chk0" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox" checked /></label><br/> 
  <label>Check Box 1: <input id="chk1" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox" /></label><br/> 
  <label>Check Box 2: <input id="chk2" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox" /></label><br/> 
  <label>Check Box 3: <input id="chk3" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="checkBox" /></label><br/> 
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" data-name="checkBox" />
</form>
```

Comment: Spelled checkbox with lower case b - see update and demo