# Checkboxes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I've got a problem. I must create a form with five **check-boxes**.

1. The user must select exactly three of the five check-boxes.
2. At the time of change check-box updates the marker at check-box
3. When the user presses a fourth element should light up at the red light.

**3. When you deselect any item marker when it disappears (is white) and the rest are green.**

Here is what I'm done: http://jsfiddle.net/epredator/98TfU/

and some of my code, because I can't post a JSfiddle link without some code in text ;):

```
 function checkGreen() {
        if (this.checked && counter >= 3) {
            console.log("if test in checkGreen()");
        }
    }
```

I've got a problem with point 3, because i don't know how to change red light to green after uncheck one of check-boxes with green light. I spend a lot of time on it. As you can see I am not the master of Javascript and ask you for help, pleas help me :) ... and for the end i must use pure JavaScript (no jQuery). Thanks a lot for help ...

Comment: If the user can select only three checkboxes, why are they allowed/able to check four, or five? Why not prevent their interacting with more than three of them?

Comment: when they check more then free check-boxes then light will be red. This is concept of that project and i can't change this.

Comment: Okay, so how does that affect whatever happens next? Checkboxes with a 'red light' aren't submitted to the database somehow? It may be a restriction of the project, but it seems a poor UI choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. It is cleaner than how you were doing it before. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y82ga/1). Keep an array of the checked boxes, and use it to determine which ones should be what color.

```
(function() {
  var checked = [];

  document.getElementById("Checkbox1").addEventListener("click",toggle);
  document.getElementById("Checkbox2").addEventListener("click",toggle);
  document.getElementById("Checkbox3").addEventListener("click",toggle);
  document.getElementById("Checkbox4").addEventListener("click",toggle);
  document.getElementById("Checkbox5").addEventListener("click",toggle);

  function toggle() {
    if (this.checked) {
        checked.push(this);
    } else {
        var index = checked.indexOf(this);
        var box = checked.splice(index,1)[0];
        box.nextElementSibling.className = "white";
    }
    refresh();
  }

  function refresh() {
    for (var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
        if (i < 3) {
            checked[i].nextElementSibling.className = "green";
        } else {
            checked[i].nextElementSibling.className = "red";
        }
    }

  }

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

For Javascript, you can use below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        // method to bind handler
        function bindEvent(element, type, handler) {
            if (element.addEventListener) {
                element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
            } else {
                element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
            }
        }

        // binding click event to all the checkboxes with name 'choice'
        // you can generalize this method
        window.onload = function () {
            var elements = document.getElementsByName('choice');
            if (!elements)
                return;

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                var ele = elements[i];
                bindEvent(ele, 'click', function () {
                    changeColor();
                });
            }
        }

        // Pass the checkbox name to the function
        // taken from stack overflow answer 
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563240/how-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes
        function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
            var checkboxesChecked = [];
            // loop over them all
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i]);
                }
            }
            // Return the array if it is non-empty, or null
            return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
        }

        // with your other function, you can call this function or club the functionality
        function changeColor() {
            var elements = document.getElementsByName('choice');

            if (!elements)
                return;

            var selectedCheckBoxes = getCheckedBoxes('choice');
            if (selectedCheckBoxes && selectedCheckBoxes.length == 3) {
                // set color to green 
            }

        }
    </script>
```

and HTML used as: (note only 'name' property from input element)

```
<span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="Checkbox1" />1</span>
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="Checkbox2" />2</span>
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="Checkbox3" />3</span>
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="Checkbox4" />4</span>
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="Checkbox5" />5</span>
```

You can get all the checked elements and if the count is 3, mark every body with interested color.