# JavaScript: Iterate over dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: javascript, loops, spring-mvc, checkbox

I would like to run validation before saving the screen.  The issue I have is that the checkboxes I need to see if they're checked are all dynamically created...

```
        <div class="availableTypes">
           <form:checkboxes path="types" items="${availableTypes}" itemValue="typeId" itemLabel="name" element="div" />
        </div>
```

Ideally I would like to get the 'value' of each of the checkboxes that are checked.

```
/**
 * Run validation on types checkboxes before saving
 */
function validateTypes() {
 // todo: get all the checkboxes
var checkedValue = [];
for (Checkbox c) {
    if(isChecked) {
       checkedValue.push(c.value);
    }
}
if (checkedValue.contains('a')) {
    return false;
} else { 
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Comment: @Johan Added javascript pseudo code

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use-case for this? Do you have several checkboxes for "I agree to the terms of service" checkboxes and you want to validate that the user has checked them all? If you want to force the user to check a checkbox, then check the box FOR them, and disable it. Don't give the user the option to uncheck it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all checked checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563240/how-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes)