# How to make javascript apply action to all checked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to javascript, and I need to make a script, that applies a couple of actions to all checked boxes, I don't know how to determine which boxes are checked, with javascript, so I can apply an action onClick, any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563240/how-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes

Comment: Thank you for the answer,but how to make an action on that element,after i know it is checked ?

Comment: make use of ajax code in js, pass selected checkbox values to  a php function & there you can perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        body { font-family: 'Roboto', serif; font-smooth: never; -webkit-font-smoothing : none; }
        #select-all { margin-right:10px }
        label { display: block }
        label:hover { cursor: pointer }
        input[type="submit"] { margin-top:20px }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <label for="select-all"><input id="select-all" type="checkbox" />Check all</label>
    <br>

    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="checkbox1" /> CheckBox 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="checkbox2" /> CheckBox 2
    </label>
    <input name="send" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#select-all').click(function (event) {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if ($_POST['checkboxes'])
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST['checkboxes']);
    echo "</pre>";
}
elseif (!$_POST['checkboxes'])
{
    echo "Nothing selected.";
}
?>
```