# Find all checked checkboxes and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to find all checkboxes and radio buttons what are checked. While I can do this:

```
var abc = document.querySelectorAll(".some_class input[type='checkbox']:checked");
```

How can I actually find **both checkboxes and radio** buttons at once? Pure javascript.

Comment: `".some_class input:checked"` This should do the trick as both radio and checkbox have checked property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all checked checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563240/how-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes)

Comment: @Yasser No. If you see the code OP has shared, he already has code to get all checkboxes. He is looking to get all checkboxes and **radios** that are checked

Comment: try using it like this `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked,input[type="radio"]:checked')`

Answer (score 5):

As commented before,

> ".some_class input:checked"

Sample:

```js
function notify(){
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
  for(var i = 0; i< els.length; i++){
    console.log(els[i].type, els[i].value)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" value="3">3
<input type="checkbox" value="4">4
<input type="checkbox" value="5">5

<br/>

<input type="radio" name="test" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="test"value="3">3
<input type="radio" name="test" value="4">4
<input type="radio" name="test" value="5">5

<button onclick="notify()"> Check </button>
```

But if you have different selectors for checkbox and radio, you can try this:

```js
function notify(){
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.chks input[type="checkbox"]:checked, .rbs input[type="radio"]:checked');
  for(var i = 0; i< els.length; i++){
    console.log(els[i].type, els[i].value)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chks">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" value="3">3
<input type="checkbox" value="4">4
<input type="checkbox" value="5">5
</div>

<div class="rbs">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="test"value="3">3
<input type="radio" name="test" value="4">4
<input type="radio" name="test" value="5">5
</div>
<button onclick="notify()"> Check </button>
```