# How can i send the value of the selected checkbox through ajax

Tags: javascript

I am getting `data` from a backend server, and I would like to know how I can send the value of the `questionid` if the checkbox is clicked.

```
function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlString = "";  
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += "<p><input type='checkbox' id='checks' value='" + data[i] + "'/>" +
      data[i].questionid + "." + "\n;
    htmlString += '</p>';
  }
  response.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
  document.getElementById('checks').onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          var Data = xhr.responseText;
          var parseData = JSON.parse(Data);
          console.log(parseData);
        }
      };
      xhr.open("POST", "URL", true);
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: You have a quote issue, but you're not even using your `renderHTML` function, so what do you expect? What shows up when you `console.log(parseData)`?

Comment: I use my renderHTML function in another function which I haven't posted. The other function is a `receive()` function which receives a list of questions attached to a checkbox. The only problem is when I click on a checkbox, I need the value of the checkbox that was clicked, and send that data using a POST request

Comment: You probably want to assign `var t = this;` outside your `xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){/* t.value here gives checkbox value */ } }` because you have issues with the `this` context being global when inside the Anonymous function. While the `this` context in an Event listening function refers to the Element itself, that context is lost when nesting non-Object property functions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use name instead id

id='checks' => name='checks'
And define fuction like  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563240/how-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of what you're asking is doable, see the code snippet below.  Instead of logging the result, you can replace that with whatever AJAX call you need to do.

Note: One of the big issues in your code (aside from the quotation-related syntax error), is that you're trying to assign `id="checks"` to multiple HTML elements, which you can't do.  When you do this, generally your `onclick` event will work for the first element, but not the rest.  Instead, use `classes`, or, use the `querySelector` like I have below.

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for (var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      console.log(this.value + ' is checked!');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox 1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox 2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox 3" />
```