# How to remove unchecked value from list?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get all checked values from checkboxes and return them in element.

I have a code:

```
this.values = []; 
if (item.checked) {
        this.values.push(item.value);
    } else {
        this.values.splice(item.value)
    }
 return alert(this.values);
```

There are few problems:

1. If I check and uncheck the same item, it pushes to array every time, so there could be same multiple values. `(this.values = [1,1,1])`
2. Splice does not remove from this.values one item.value that was unchecked, it removes all values and make this.values empty `(this.values = []);`

What I need is:
if I have item values for example: 1 , 2 , 3

And check every item, that my array will become - `this.values = [1 , 2 , 3]`

If I uncheck item number 2, `this.values = [1, 3]`

Comment: I think it might suit you: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: @NikitaMadeev: That's only going to help in case of setting values, but he needs help in case of removal.

Comment: @Pritesh [Set.prototype.delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete)??

Comment: Not entirely clear from your question, are you trying to remove an item from an array?

Comment: Not exactly. I need to store checked values in array. But if they unchecked - remove them. For example, I checked item number 1, arr = [1], I uncheck - arr = []. If there multiple choices to make - I checked item 1, 2 and 3. arr will become [1 , 2, 3]. I uncheck just number 1, arr goes to [2,3]. Something like this

Comment: Related: [How to get all checked checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563240/how-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes/31113246).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a common class for all the checkbox, then use `document.querySelectorAll` to get the checkbox and attach event listener to each of the box.

Now on `change` even call another function and first `filter` out the `checked` checkbox then use `map` to get an array of the check box value

```js
let elem = [...document.querySelectorAll('.checkBox')]
elem.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('change', getChecked))

function getChecked() {
  let getChex = elem.filter(item => item.checked).map(item => item.value)
  console.log(getChex)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="one" class="checkBox">
<label for="one">1</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="two" class="checkBox">
<label for="two">2</label>

<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="three" class="checkBox">
<label for="three">3</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, you can do this:

```
this.values = []; 
if (item.checked) {
    if(!this.values.includes(item.value)) {
       this.values.push(item.value);
    }
} else {
    if(indexOf(item.value) !== -1){
       this.values.splice(this.values.indexOf(item.value), 1)
    }
}
return alert(this.values);
```

Insert `item.value` only if `this.values` does not contains value and use `splice` with index (if item is in `this.value`).

Comment: This is goode one, but what if my values won't be numbers, but words for example? I tried to do this with numbers values and thats works great, but with words splice do not remove from array

Comment: Ciao, I updated my answer with a solution that is valid for number and string.

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't show your html file. I just posted the code works for me for your reference.

```
function getSelectedCheckboxValues(name) {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`);
    let values = [];
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value);
    });
    return values;
}
```

if you are editing js in the HTML,
replace

```
 const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`);
```

with

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="color"]:checked');
```

source: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-checkbox/