# How to target ".switch-field input:checked" to make changes in CSS properties with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, checked

How can Javascript change CSS properties of `input:checked`

**CSS**

```
   .switch-field input:checked + label {
    background-color: #018786;
    color:white;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Lets say I want to change its background color-

**JS**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("switch-field input:checked")[0].style.background= #4400ff;
```

How can i target that specific "class" with "input checked" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all checked checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563240/how-to-get-all-checked-checkboxes)

Comment: In CSS you are applying the background to the label but in css you are changing the background of the input. Is that a copy paste error or this is actually your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

Basically the steps you need to follow are

1. Clear all the label background style property
2. Select all the `input:checked + label` (thats the element which has the background color property)
3. Loop through all the fetched labels
4. Change the background color to what you want

### Gotcha to be aware of

1. Changing the background property via javascript will not change it back automatically when the input is unchecked
2. You will need to run a clear/update function on the `input`'s `onChange` event to ensure it sets the backgrounds properly on checking an unchecking the input

### Suggestions

1. Use the CSS `input:checked + label` and `input + label` classes to add your backgrounds
2. Always try to avoid javascript manipulation of styles, it's against the `convention` and usually considered as bad practice if it can be avoided

### Solution

```js
function clickHandle() {
  // Clear all the labels background style property to ensure it resets to the css class background property
  clearLabelBackground();

  // Get all the labels (not input) based on the css input:checked flag
  // We are getting the label because that if the element which has the background color property you want to change
  var selectedLabels = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked + label");
  
  // Loop through each of the fetched labels
  selectedLabels.forEach((label)=>{
    
    // Change the background color style
    label.style.background="#4400ff"; 

  });
}

function clearLabelBackground() {
  // Get all the labels (not input) regardless of the selection
  // We are getting the label because that if the element which has the background color property you want to change
  var selectedLabels = document.querySelectorAll("input + label");
  
  // Loop through each of the fetched labels
  selectedLabels.forEach((label)=>{
    
    // Remove the background color style
    label.style.background=""; 

  });

}
```

```css
.switch-field input:checked + label {
    background-color: #018786;
    color:white;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-field">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <label>Item 1</label>
</div>
<div class="switch-field">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <label>Item 2</label>
</div>
<div class="switch-field">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <label>Item 3</label>
</div>
<div class="switch-field">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <label>Item 4</label>
</div>

<button onclick="clickHandle()">Change BG</button>
```

*I have commented the javascript code, if you need more clarification, feel free to comment on this answer*

Comment: Sorry i should have given you response earlier, thanks a ton..

Comment: It is working like intended ...

Comment: Thats great to hear. Could you mark it as answered in that case. Thanks.

Comment: That was bothering me for long, I am still learning - If you get time please do check my project,  i have used your code to take color input and then using the value to change the Switch button's background - 
  https://www.mediafire.com/file/9cmqp4034hqgqgh/Project_for_Eagnir.html/file

Comment: Thanks for sharing the project. It's a great start. You should look into using [javascript object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) to store and update settings (like color input you take at the bottom) and also look into [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) instead of `table` to place the number controls. Good job so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector` for single element or `querySelectorAll` for multiple elements. You can use CSS query in that.

```
document.querySelector("switch-field input:checked").style.background = 
 "#4400ff";
```