# Javascript check all checkboxes in classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

This is my first time asking question in Stackoverflow

i have a same problem to select specific boxes in asp

i refer to the older post as

[Javascript check all checkboxes in a table / asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543017/javascript-check-all-checkboxes-in-a-table-asp-net)

```
function toggleCheckBoxes(elem) {
  var div = document.getElementById('<% = divid.ClientID %>');
  var chk = div.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var len = chk.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (chk[i].type === 'checkbox') {
        chk[i].checked = elem.checked;
    }
  }
}
```

and then

```
'CheckAll
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="toggleCheckBoxes(this)" />
```

but my boxes which were :

```
response.Write "</td>"
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_1 "
if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(9))="1" then 
  response.Write " checked"
response.Write "/>1</td>"
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_2 "
if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(10))="1" then 
  response.Write " checked"
response.Write "/>2</td>"
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_3 "
if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(11))="1" then 
  response.Write " checked"
response.Write "/>3</td>"
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_4 "
if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(12))="1" then 
  response.Write " checked"
response.Write "/>4</td>"
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_5 "
if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(13))="1" then 
  response.Write " checked"
response.Write "/>5</td>"
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox  name=process_6 "
if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(14))="1" then 
  response.Write " checked"
response.Write "/>6</td>"
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox  name=process_7 "
if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(15))="1" then 
  response.Write " checked"
response.Write "/>7</td>"
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_8 "
if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(16))="1" then 
  response.Write " checked"
response.Write "/>8</td>"
response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_9 "
if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(17))="1" then 
  response.Write " checked"
response.Write "/>9</td>"
response.Write "</tr>"
response.Write "</table>"
```

how do i select them all / unselect them

Please help.

Comment: you have to do this from javascript?

Comment: can i do this in asp way   , please help

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery you can try this:

```
function CheckAll(IsChecked) {
            $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', IsChecked));
            });
        }
```

or even better if you toggle them based on another check box like this

```
 function CheckAll() {
            $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', $('#ChkAll').is(':checked'));
            });
        }
```

Comment: thx for answer ~  but i dont think i can use jquery and i dont know how to use         i need to check thiose specific boxes control by one box (checkall) . ANd i donno how to write it~

Comment: It is simple. jquery is a javascript based library. Simply a .js file which you reference into you page like any other js file. all you have to do is add onclick for ChkAll check box like this, onclick="CheckAll()". If you want to learn jquery and I think you should check these sites http://learn.jquery.com/ & http://www.jquery.com/

Comment: Arabic P ,  how do i put a id? (onclick?) in asp or sth to  "identify"  the JS function?

Comment: my checkall checkbox code is : response.Write "<input type='checkbox'  id='checkall'><label for='checkall'>checkall</label>"

Comment: response.Write "<input type='checkbox' id='ChkAll' onclick='CheckAll();'><label for='checkall'>checkall</label>"

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options using javascript or code :

1)Javascript by following this code :

```
     function toggleCheckBoxes(rb){
        var rbs = $('#rbData :radio');
        for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
            if (rbs[i] != rb) 
                rbs[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
```

2)Code by changing your input type to asp:checkbox and make it autopostback = true and onSelectedIndexChangd() function,toogle the checkbox

Comment: Thx for answering Mr.Ahmed     what would i write the checkall boxes and add function into my another boxes if i use your js function?

Comment: hmm i don't get what you mean by this "what would i write the checkall boxes and add function into my another boxes if i use your js function"

but just add this javascript function in your code and call it when you click on checkall box

Comment: i mean i dont how to follow this on my program  2)Code by changing your input type to asp:checkbox and make it autopostback = true and onSelectedIndexChangd() function,toogle the checkbox

Comment: Mr. Ahmed , sry for my poor expression ..  i have put your JS function on my program already ..   but i dont know use it (with a checkall box and how to put autopostback = true and onSelectedIndexChangd() (that mean i donno how to follow the part 2 step)  -.-"

Comment: aah i see ,no part 2 is another solution from code ,(1) is a solution and (2) is another solution. you can do whenever you want

Comment: can i ask if i like to idenify my box?  :  response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_8 "
    if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(16))="1" then response.Write " checked"
    response.Write "/>8</td>"           could i put the "id" on it if i use your first solution? and how can i do that?  pls help..

Comment: you can put the id tag normally like you did for the name tag. and this javascript function doesnt look for id,it search for any input of type checkbox and get it,you don't need the id of each checkbox

Comment: Now my Checkall box is : response.Write "<input type='checkbox' id='checkall'><label for='checkall'>checkall</label>"


and my JS Function :  function checkall()

document.getElementById('checkall').onclick = function () {
    var inputs = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('input'),
        checked = this.checked;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox')
            inputs[i].checked = checked;
    }
}


and my boxes which be controlled are : response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox id=container name=process_1 "

Comment: i agree but you didn't say when to call this function checkall()..you have to add inside the input id of checllall ,add function called onclick="checkall();return false;"

Answer (score 0):

Select/unselect all checkbox is nothing to do with asp.net ,I think.
Add an `id` attribute to your table, and add a checkbox associated with a 'checkall' label and define its onclick event handler.

And this is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K3dRA/), you can check it and try to update your own code.

**UPDATE:**
Even I have no experience about `asp.net`,but some advices:
Try to use loop statement if possible, try to use an IDE that support `ASP` syntax checking and highlighting, try to learn some common debugging methods.

I think it will help you.

Comment: this is what i have to do! .... but i got a error when i add id = container what should i do if my box is response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox name=process_1 " if mEditRecMode and ConvertNullToString(mConsigneeArray(9))="1" then response.Write " checked" response.Write "/>1</td>"

Comment: @Luk You need to add `""` and escape them when you add `id` attribute.I mean like this, `response.Write "<table id=\"container\">"`

Comment: it appear an error with "Declare"   when i use   "<table id=\"container\">"    could u give a detail answer for me?

Comment: the JS fucntion is working fine , but i cant put your "<input type="checkbox" id="checkall"><label for="checkall">checkall</label>"  into my program ... could you help me on this?

Comment: I think it's `asp` syntax error. Any nested `"` should be escaped, like `response.Write "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkall\"><label for=\"checkall\">checkall</label>"`, or replace `"` into `'`, like `response.Write "<input type='checkbox' id='checkall'><label for='checkall'>checkall</label>"`.

Comment: yes , it ok now  if my checkall box is " response.Write "<input type='checkbox' id='checkall'><label for='checkall'>checkall</label>""    so how about if i write those boxes plus an identification ?

Comment: i tried response.Write "<td nowrap><input type=checkbox id=container name=process_1 "     which add id=container  on those boxes (no error) but it doesn't work

Comment: Add `id` or `class` attribute to html tags will affect nothing, if you haven't defined relevant css rules.

Comment: huh? what should i do?

Comment: @Luk God.. Add `id` attribute to `table` tag which includes all the checkbox you wanna select/unselect, not every `td` tag.And add checkall outside that `table`. Like what my demo does.

Comment: Oic , same as i (dont have any exp on asp) , anyways , thx for your help~